# Ubuntu latest version timer that does everything that i ask it to do in this Post description?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, downloads, time

I'm looking for a timer that sounds every time that pass the time passes that I configure it to show me when it passes, after configuring it to show me. I want a timer that can count even seconds like a stopwatch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### GNOME Clocks

A simple and elegant clock application. It includes world clocks, alarms, a stopwatch and a timer.

Goals:

- Show the time in different cities around the world
- Set alarms to wake you up
- Measure elapsed time with an accurate stopwatch
- Set timers to properly cook your food

To install the GNOME Clocks application in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnome-clocks
```